# Getting error that variable was already declared, inside a while loop

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

I am getting an error saying that `ID` was already declared, so it cannot be declared again in my `while` loop. Then how do I increment my loop?

```
int RealID = 100;
Console.WriteLine("Enter Number");
int ID = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

while( ID != ReadID)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect ID. Enter another number");
    int ID = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
Console.WriteLine("You entered the correct ID");
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, don't declare it again... just assign the new value:

```
while (ID != ReadID)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect ID. Enter another number");
    ID = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By prefacing your variable `ID` with a type, you are in fact re-declaring it.

Reuse it instead of re-declaring it by assigning the new value to it.

```
int RealID = 100;
Console.WriteLine("Enter Number");
int ID = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

while( ID != ReadID)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect ID. Enter another number");
    ID = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
Console.WriteLine("You entered the correct ID");
```